# Is majorization a total order on finite non-negative integers of fixed length?

Tags: combinatorics, convex-analysis

Let $N$ be some positive integer, and consider finite sequences of natural numbers $x,y$ whose sum equals $N$.

We can in some cases build a total order among these sequences, provided we identify sequences differing only by the ordering of the elements.

For example, for $N=2$ we have $(1,1)\prec(2,0)$.
Similarly, for $N=3$, we have
$$(1,1,1)\prec(2,1,0) \prec (3,0,0).$$
For $N=4$, we have
$$(1111)\prec(2110)\prec (2200)\prec (3100)\prec(4000).$$
Again, for $N=5$ we have the sequence:
$$(11111)\prec(21110)\prec (22100)\prec (31100)\prec(32000)\prec(41000)\prec(50000).$$
How can we show that this always works (if it does)?
More precisely, how do we show that the set of all non-increasing tuples of $N$ elements between $0$ and $N$ can be totally ordered via majorization?

Comment: Is majorization different from lexicographic ordering?

Comment: @DanielFischer With the conditions set in this problem, no.

Comment: @URL isn't that inconsistent with your answer, being lexicographic ordering a total order?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It’s actually that, when an ordered sequence majorizes another, then it’s lexicographically bigger than the latter. But not necessarily backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails for $N=6$. The sequences $(3,1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,2,0)$ are incomparable, as $$3>2,$$ $$3+1+1<2+2+2.$$ In fact, all $N\geq6$ fail, since both $$(3,\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{N-3\text{ 1s}}),$$ $$(2,2,2,\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{N-6\text{ 1s}},0)$$ are incomparable too.